# How to run multivariate foreach loop

Tags: stata

I would like to run a multivariate loop in Stata to rename many variables.

The following code is how i would imagine it would work:

```
local varlist1 "x1 x2 x3 .... xn" 
local varlist2 "a b c .... n" 

foreach i in local `varlist1' & j in local `varlist2' {
rename `i' `j'
}
```

The objective of this would be to rename `x1` to `a` and `x2` to `b` and so on.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: As answers imply, Stata doesn't allow that syntax or anything like it. If it did it would be closer to `foreach i of local varlist1 & j of local varlist2` but the form is still ambiguous whether you want all possible pairs or parallel loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need a loop at all as

```
rename (x1 x2 x3 xn) (a b c n)
```

is perfectly legal, given some constraints on whether the new names are in use for other variables.

Given interest in loops, here's another slow way to do it:

```
local new a b c n 
foreach old in x1 x2 x3 xn { 
    gettoken this new : new 
    rename `old' `this' 
}
```

Here `new` is treated as a stack: each time around the loop, we take off the top item and do not replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following toy example:

```
clear
set obs 1

forvalues i = 1 / 3 {
    generate x`i' = runiform()
}

list

     +--------------------------------+
     |       x1         x2         x3 |
     |--------------------------------|
  1. | .3913819   .1196613   .7542434 |
     +--------------------------------+
```

Here's one way to do what you want:

```
local varlist1 "x1 x2 x3" 
local varlist2 "a b c" 

tokenize `varlist2'
local i 0
foreach var1 of local varlist1 {
    local ++i
    rename `var1' ``i''
}

list

     +--------------------------------+
     |        a          b          c |
     |--------------------------------|
  1. | .5844658   .3697791   .8506309 |
     +--------------------------------+
```

The idea here is to break up the local macro `varlist2` in separate arguments `1`, `2`, `3` etc. and then move through them using a counter local macro `i`.

Alternatively, you can simply do:

```
local varlist1 "x1 x2 x3" 
local varlist2 "a b c" 

rename (`varlist1') (`varlist2')
```

or:

```
rename x# (`varlist2')
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, certainly not the most elegant way, is to use the extended macro function `word i of`. A sample solution is:

```
local varlist1 "x1 x2 x3 .... xn" 
local varlist2 "a b c .... n" 

local numitems = wordcount("`varlist1'")

forv i=1/`numitems' {
    local old_name : word `i' of `varlist1'
    local new_name : word `i' of `varlist2'
    rename `old_name' `new_name'
}
```